# Removing the Leaflet draw toolbar when added as Leaflet control

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, toolbar

I add a [draw-toolbar](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html#l-draw-toolbar) (I'm using the my own version from the example "Disabling a toolbar item")

```
drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        polygon: false,
        marker: false
    },
    edit: {
        featureGroup: drawnItems 
    }
});
map.addControl(drawControl);
```

This works great but I can't remove the created toolbar with all the handlers.
How can I achieve this?

I tried:

```
map.removeControl(drawControl);             //dosent remove handlers
drawControl.remove();                       //dosent remove handlers
drawControl.removeToolbar();                //dosent find function
drawControl._toolbars.edit.removeToolbar(); //dosent find function
drawControl._toolbars.draw.removeToolbar(); //dosent find function
drawControl._toolbars.removeToolbar();      //dosent find function
```

**Edit for better understanding of my problem**

The documentation claims that I can add a toolbar like these:

```
var toolbar = L.Toolbar();
toolbar.addToolbar(map);
```

How ever this gives me a `this.callInitHooks is not a function` TypeError and it's not what i need because I want to customize the buttons depending on what the user can edit.

So I go with the `drawControl` version for the toolbar. But for this verion there is no function like `removeToolbar()`.

The only thing I coud find was the first two of my "I tried" exampels. But this only remove the html container and not the class with all the handels like the removeToolbar() function. (At least thats was I think it does when I look at the code from the removeToolbar() function ).

**Redraw**

```
var drawControl = "";

function addToolbar() {
    if( drawControl !== "" ) {
        /* remove old toolbar */
        map.removeControl(drawControl);             //dosent remove handlers
        drawControl.remove();                       //dosent remove handlers
        drawControl.removeToolbar();                //dosent find function
        drawControl._toolbars.edit.removeToolbar(); //dosent find function
        drawControl._toolbars.draw.removeToolbar(); //dosent find function
        drawControl._toolbars.removeToolbar();      //dosent find function
    }

    /* draws new toolbar (with different drawnItems and e.g. marker: true)*/
    drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);
    drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            polygon: false,
            marker: false
        },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems 
        }
    });
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function( e ) {
        console.log('created');
    });
}
```

But because it not fully removes the old toolbar. It fires the `L.Draw.Event.CREATED` also from the old toolbar.

**So how can I fully remove the old toolbar?**

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by "all the handlers"?

Comment: The draw-events are still firing when i redraw the the toolbar with different settings.

Comment: What do you mean with "redraw the toolbar with different settings"? Can you please edit the question and exactly describe all the steps that lead to undesired behavior? What are this undesired events end when are they triggered?

Comment: @TomazicM I edited the question. I hope you have now all information you need.